# WPF Get Thumbnail of folder

Tags: c#, wpf, thumbnails

I want to get the thumbnail image of a folder but I didn't find any way how to do it with WPF. For UWP there is a function `StorageFolder.GetThumbnailAsync()`. But at WPF I didn't find any solution to this.

[image: folder icon]

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/2994451/1360389 maybe help.

Comment: Already tried but it only works for files

Comment: have you tried `ShellFolder`?

Comment: Thank you, I cannot believe I didn't figure it out myself. It was just `ShellFolder.FromParsingName(FolderPath).Thumbnail.BitmapSource` It works and it's also a way better than at UWP. It also gives you the real thumbnail of the folder, not just the default empty one. Post it as an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Windows API Code Pack](https://github.com/contre/Windows-API-Code-Pack-1.1) mentioned on http://stackoverflow.com/a/2994451/1360389 maybe help.
Use `ShellFile.FromFilePath(FilePath).Thumbnail.BitmapSource` for file and
use `ShellFolder.FromParsingName(FolderPath).Thumbnail.BitmapSource` for folder.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do it in not a very clean way via pinvoke but it's working as it should see code (use the `GetIcon` method):

```
 public static class UITools
    {
        private const uint FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL = 0x00000080;
        private const uint FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = 0x00000010;

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts a <see cref="System.Drawing.Bitmap"/> into a WPF <see cref="BitmapSource"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>Uses GDI to do the conversion. Hence the call to the marshalled DeleteObject.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <param name="source">The source bitmap.</param>
        /// <returns>A BitmapSource</returns>
        public static BitmapSource ToBitmapSource(this System.Drawing.Bitmap source)
        {
            BitmapSource bitSrc = null;

            var hBitmap = source.GetHbitmap();

            try
            {
                bitSrc = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                    hBitmap,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    Int32Rect.Empty,
                    BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
            }
            catch (Win32Exception)
            {
                bitSrc = null;
            }
            finally
            {
                DeleteObject(hBitmap);
            }

            return bitSrc;
        }

        public static BitmapSource GetIcon(string path,bool isDirectory)
        {
            IntPtr hIcon = GetJumboIcon(GetIconIndex(path,isDirectory));
            BitmapSource icon = null;

            using (Icon ico = (Icon)System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(hIcon).Clone())
            {

                icon = ico.ToBitmap().ToBitmapSource();
            }

            DestroyIcon(hIcon);

            return icon;
        }

        internal static int GetIconIndex(string pszFile,bool isDirectory)
        {
            uint attributes = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL;
            if (isDirectory)
                attributes |= FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY;

            SHFILEINFO sfi = new SHFILEINFO();
            NativeMethods.SHGetFileInfo(pszFile
                , attributes //0
                , ref sfi
                , (uint)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(sfi)
                , (uint)(SHGFI.SysIconIndex | SHGFI.LargeIcon | SHGFI.UseFileAttributes));
            return sfi.iIcon;
        }

        // 256*256
        internal static IntPtr GetJumboIcon(int iImage)
        {
            IImageList spiml = null;
            Guid guil = new Guid(IID_IImageList); //or IID_IImageList2

            SHGetImageList(SHIL_EXTRALARGE, ref guil, ref spiml);
            IntPtr hIcon = IntPtr.Zero;
            spiml.GetIcon(iImage, ILD_TRANSPARENT | ILD_IMAGE, ref hIcon); //

            return hIcon;
        }

    }
```

As you can see this applies to files and folders.
you can see it in action with a small tool that i made a while ago :
[GitHub](https://github.com/hmz777/Z-Toolbar)

Comment: Why are you passing `SHIL_EXTRALARGE` instead of `SHIL_JUMBO` (`0x0004`)? Just curious, your method is named `GetJumboIcon()`

Comment: Btw, there are also means to get a byte array from `hIcon`, so it can be passed to [IconBitmapDecoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.iconbitmapdecoder) (as a MemoryStream), to  remove `System.Drawing` from the premises. But that's another story.

Comment: @Jimi i was experimenting with the size flags, the `SHIL_JUMBO` gave me clear icons but with pixelated edges and the WPF anti aliasing didn't help me with this situation while the `SHIL_EXTRALARGE` gave me icons as clear as jumbo but with soft edges, and i forgot to change the method name at that time.

Comment: Yes, that happens when the Icon in Jumbo size is not available, so an Icon of Jumbo size (256x256) is returned anyway, but it's actually the largest (last) Icon in the list, enlarged to the size requested. You could add a parameter to the method, where the User can specify a `SHIL_` values in the form of an enumerator (I'm not saying to you should change anything here, of course, it could simply make more clear - for those who don't know what's happening - what the options are). It's also true that anti-aliasing in WPF has ...it's own will.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you, i didn't know about the enlargement behavior.